# PHP function working differently for return and echo. Why?

Tags: php, function, return, echo

By using the following class:

```
class SafeGuardInput{

    public $form;
    public function __construct($form)
    {
        $this->form=$form;
        $trimmed=trim($form);
        $specialchar=htmlspecialchars($trimmed);
        $finaloutput=stripslashes($specialchar);
        echo $finaloutput;
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        unset($finaloutput);
    }
}
```

and Calling the function, by the following code, it works fine.

```
        <?php 
        require('source/class.php');
        $target="<script></script><br/>";
        $forminput=new SafeGuardInput($target);
        ?>
```

But if in the SafeGuardInput class if I replace **echo $finaloutput;** with **return $finaloutput;** and then **echo $forminput;** on the index.php page. It DOES NOT WORK. Please provide a solution.

Comment: "It does not work" is not an adequate description of the problem, no matter how hard you hit capslock.

Comment: `$finaloutput` is only a local variable... unknown in the destructor

Comment: Got the point. Thanks for helping the noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return anything from a constructor. The `new` keyword always causes the newly created object to be assigned to the variable on the left side of the statement. So the variable you've used is already taken. Once you remember that, you quickly realise there is nowhere to put anything else that would be returned from the constructor!

A valid approach would be to write a function which will output the data when requested:

```
class SafeGuardInput{

    public $form;
    public function __construct($form)
    {
        $this->form=$form;
    }

    public function getFinalOutput()
    {
        $trimmed = trim($this->form);
        $specialchar = htmlspecialchars($trimmed);
        $finaloutput = stripslashes($specialchar);
        return $finaloutput;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like in the normal way like this:

```
$obj = new SafeGuardInput($target);
echo $obj->getFinalOutput();
```

Comment: In the public function getFinalOutput, $form remains undefined variable.